# error: no such partition ошибка после удаления раздела с Linux mint

Tags: linux, bios

Решил поставить Mint как вторую систему. Были проблемы с чёрным экраном после установки. Снес разделы с Linux через стандартную утилиту windows, чтобы потом поставить другой дистрибутив. В итоге, перезагружаю ноутбук , возникает эта ошибка. Записал Ubuntu на флешку, но bios её не видит. Подскажите, что делать.)

Update:
Спасибо за советы. Но теперь возникла новая проблема. Установил Ubuntu. Но после выбора системы в grub, что в Ubuntu , что в Windows показывает чёрный экран, команда nomodeset не помогает, все также чёрный экран. Похоже ноут отторгает линуксоидные системы)

Comment: Фиксбут с установочной флешки винды

Comment: *Подскажите, что делать* —- смотря чего вы хотите добиться (и что именно вам в этом мешает).

Comment: Можно поробовать заново установить linux, при установке linux покажет вам все разделы на диске, выберете который предназначен для linux, при установке также скажите установить GRUB. Если все будет хорошо, то GRUB найдет раздел с виндой и сделает вам возможность выбора системы при старте

Comment: В биосе нужно найти дисковый старинный режим **FAT** вместо **AHCI**. Этот режим нужно проставить только при установке.

Comment: @eri сделал фиксбут, винда запускается, но хотелось бы все равно поставить рядом линукс. Поставил снова линукс, та же проблема с чёрным экраном, когда запускаю windows или ubuntu/mint, nomodeset не помогает, слышал что это только для nvidia карт, у меня в ноуте стоит amd. Может какая-то несовместимость с железякой?

Comment: какое поколение amd?

Comment: @eri Проц - amd-a8-4500m, видеокарта - AMD Radeon HD 7640G + HD 8570M Dual Graphics

Comment: Llano обычно без проблем стартует. наверное проблема с Dual Graphics

Answer (score 0):

Удивительно, но просто вставил флешку в другой порт и bios ее увидел. Хотя предыдущий работает отлично. Спасибо за советы.

---

Но теперь возникла новая проблема. Установил Ubuntu. Но после выбора системы в grub, что в Ubuntu , что в Windows показывает чёрный экран, команда nomodeset не помогает, все также чёрный экран. Похоже ноут отторгает линуксоидные системы)

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно. Или отредактируйте этот (это допустимо, если нет ответов от других участников). Поле ответа предназначено только для ответов.

Comment: запишите образ linux на флешку и загрузитесь с флешки. Если с флешки linux будет работать, то и с диска должен работать.

Comment: Когда гружусь с флешки , все работает, но при загрузке системы с grub , чёрный экран

Comment: @VladimirPechenevskyi, как вам уже написали - создаёте новый вопрос. Один вопрос - один вопрос) Ответ - не место для нового вопроса)